# Custom Adapter affects whole layout instead of a list item/row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

Hi I am trying to implement my own custom adapter.

What I am trying to have is a list with the items like below:

[Image Text]

[Image Text]

...

I filled a list with temporary items like SONGNAME1, SONGNAME2 etc. Then run the code here is what get:

It shows only the last element of the list on the whole screen. What I am expecting was doing this effect to each list row.

[image: Here is what I get:]

You can find the related code pieces below.

This is the main activity:

```
...
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        List<ListHolder> list = setList();
        CustomAdapter adp = new CustomAdapter(list,getApplicationContext());

        if (s == null) {
            mListView.setAdapter(adp);

        }
    }


    private List<ListHolder> setList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<ListHolder> list = new ArrayList<ListHolder>();

        ListHolder l = new ListHolder();

        setContentView(R.layout.adapter);

        l.song_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        l.artist_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dist);
        l.thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            l.song_name.setText("SONGNAME"+i);
            l.artist_name.setText("ARTISTNAME"+i);
            l.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("a URL"));
            list.add(l);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

And this is adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<ListHolder> list;
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(List<ListHolder> list, Context ctx) {
    //super(ctx, R.layout.adapter, list);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = ctx;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ListHolder holder = new ListHolder();
    // First let's verify the convertView is not null

    if (convertView == null) {

        // This a new view we inflate the new layout

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);

        // Now we can fill the layout with the right values

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

        TextView distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.song_name = tv;
        holder.artist_name = distView;
        holder.thumbnail = img;
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{

        holder = (ListHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.song_name.setText("song name");

    holder.artist_name.setText("artist name");
    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("a URL"));
    //holder.img.setImageResource(p.getIdImg());


    v.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));

    return v;

}
```

This is adapter.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="8dp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is with your xml file.

Comment: ok i am posting adapter.xml file

Comment: This line looks suspicious to me: `setContentView(R.layout.adapter);

Comment: @EranGoldin If I dont put that line it gives me null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

The height of imageview and relativelayout should be wrap_content.
Also temove the setContentView () function in setList method ().

Comment: this is  not what i am asking

Comment: if I remove that line it gives me null pointer exception. l.song_name becomes null